# Can't use 'date_add'-function in sparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

In SparkR (spark-1.4.0) I want to use the `date_add` function.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/

But when I type it in SparkR it says that the function does not exist. How can that be and how can I get it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you link to is for version 1.5.2. It is possible that your version may not have this function yet. According to comments below you will need to update Spark and SparkR.

Comment: Is there a quick way to update sparkR so I can get this version?

Comment: @OlePetersen use the [source](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/R/pkg).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Not THAT simple - SparkR version should match Spark version - easier to install new version of Spark altogether

Comment: Thanks @desertnaut, I'll amend my answer.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Actually it can be used in 1.4 as long as you pass it as a SQL expression.

Answer (score 1):

In 1.4.0 it can be invoked using raw SQL:

```r
library(magrittr)

hiveContext <- sparkRHive.init(sc)

df <- createDataFrame(hiveContext, data.frame(ts=c("2015-12-01"))) %>%  
    select(alias(cast(.$ts, "date"), "ts"))

df %>% selectExpr("ts", "date_add(ts, 1) AS next_day") %>% head

##          ts   next_day
## 1 2015-12-01 2015-12-02
```

Comment: When I type hiveContext <- sparkRHive.init(sc) I get this message: "Error: Spark SQL is not built with Hive support".

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-hive-and-jdbc-support